# nginx rewrite if file exists / pattern is matched

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, slim

I'm currently trying to integrate [Munee](http://mun.ee/) in an existing [Slim 3](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/) application.

The Problem is that Slim does the Routing in the app and needs nginx to redirect all non-existing files to index.php to do so.

Munee, on the other hand, needs a redirect for some file extensions to be able to cache/minify/etc. them.

I tried for about 4 Hours now, read through everything on SO and Google and didn't find a working solution.

Things I've tried:

1.

```
location ~ \.(css|less|scss|js|coffee|jpg|png|gif|jpeg) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /munee.php?files=/$1 break;
}
try_files $uri /index.php;
```

2.

```
rewrite ^/(.*\.(?:css|less|scss|js|coffee|jpg|png|gif|jpeg))$ /munee.php?files=/$1 break;

try_files $uri /index.php;
```

3.

```
location ~ \.(css|less|scss|js|coffee|jpg|png|gif|jpeg) {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*) /munee.php?files=/$1 last;
    }
}
try_files $uri /index.php;
```

Also, I tried to redirect all traffic to index.php to be able to process everything in PHP, but if the file existed, it was still just presented directly.

If someone has an alternative to Munee, it would greatly appreciate it, but I think it does exactly what I need and nothing more... Assetic just seems so overloaded and unnecessary complicated.

EDIT (as requested):

At the end of the nginx config, there is this section:

```
location /index.php {
       fastcgi_connect_timeout 3s;     # default of 60s is just too long
       fastcgi_read_timeout 10s;       # default of 60s is just too long
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;    # assumes you are running php-fpm      locally on port 9000
   }
```

Comment: your second solution seems to be fine. what is the result of requesting some `js` or `css` file?

Comment: The result is the file being found and directly being downloaded/shown from the browser. This shouldn't happen, as Munee needs to process the files before.